# Using Google Fonts API

Tags: css, webfonts

I am new to Google Fonts.  I have gotten this URL from Google:

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

My question is, how to use the various fonts I have selected.  They are, as you can see, Ubuntu Normal 400, Ubuntu Normal 400 Italic, Ubuntu Bold 700, and Ubuntu 700 italic.

I have tried everything but can only use plain "Ubuntu" and nothing else.

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is me using italic version of this: http://jsfiddle.net/6wzuy/

```
font-family:ubuntu;
font-style:italic;
font-weight: 700;
```

The technique is to use [CSS font-style Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-style.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but can't I achieve the same effect by just selecting the default font? I mean, why then does Google allow you to select bold and italic versions of the same font?

Comment: Can you illustrate what do you mean ? All you need to do is declare ubuntu as the default font in the body css, then whenever you need to add italics or bold to text you add `font-style:italic;` to that id, class, or element.

Comment: Sure. If you look at [the Google fonts page](http://www.google.com/webfonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:), they let you pick eight different fonts, including bold and italic. But they don't seem necessary to achieve what you want. Wondering if I'm missing something here.

Comment: @symlynk I think this is what you mean : http://jsfiddle.net/Yksxf/ just add `<b> or <i>` elements.

Comment: No, it isn't the same to just add a bold or italic style if you don't have it linked.  The browser doesn't always do a great job of doing it itself.  If you want your text to look good make sure you always include the font style.  Here's an article that talks about it http://www.alistapart.com/articles/say-no-to-faux-bold/

Answer (score 2):

```
font-family: 'Ubuntu', Arial, serif; font-weight: 700;
```

EDIT: You have to include separate font libraries of italics and bolds in order for them to work as intended.

If you don't include the italic and bold versions, the browser will try to compensate, but will more than likely do a very poor job.  More about this in [this List Apart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/say-no-to-faux-bold/).

If you want to add font styles to your fonts, **always** add the extra font styles to and specify it in your document.  Especially in large serif font it can make a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks, but can't I achieve the same effect by just selecting the default font? I mean, why then does Google allow you to select bold and italic versions of the same font?

Comment: I edited the post, sorry I didn't fully understand your question at first.

Answer (score 2):

The [Google code](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,400italic,700,700italic) you use declares regular, italic, bold, and bold italic typeface (specific font) as members of the font (font family) “Ubuntu”. This implies that you use italic and bolding just as you do when using normal fonts.

You can use `font-style: italic` to request for italic typeface and `font-weight: bold` (or, equivalently, `font-weight: 700`) to request bolding. Note that many HTML elements imply italic or bold by default; for example, `h1`, `strong`, and `th` elements imply `font-weight: bold`.

There are other ways of using `@font-face` so that each typeface is declared as a font family of its own; FotSquirrel does that. But the approach applied by Google is more logical and compatible with the way fonts are generally used in HTML and in CSS.